# Where can I find this cmd skin?

Tags: cmd.exe, cmder

I was looking at the Heroku homepage and a video popped up with this commandline interface...

[image: screenshot]

It looks way better than the default cmd look, I was hoping someone knew what preset/skin that was (and if it could be applied to cmder).

Comment: Looks like [powerline](https://powerline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#screenshots)

Comment: @LotPings looks about right. Is it possible to install for Windows (e.g. for using with Cmder)? The docs don't have a Windows installation section, so that's not a promising sign...